# Analog input together with LoRaWAN

Tags: networking, hardware, analog-to-digital, hat

I am looking for a hardware configuration enabling me to read an analog input from ammeter and collect the historical data and send them over LoRa to a server.

So I could use something like [Monarco HAT](http://rpishop.cz/rex-controls/610-monarco-hat.html) together with [Dragino LoRa hat](http://rpishop.cz/rozsirujici-moduly/1230-raspberry-pi-loragps-hat.html), but I have absolutely no idea if this could work together and how to find a box to accommodate such a configuration.

Not sure if the question belongs here. I have no experience with Raspberry Pi so far.

From the Monarco HAT website FAQ:

> Can I use multiple HATs with a single Raspberry Pi?
>
> No, HATs are not stackable by definition. A HAT has to have an EEPROM
> onboard that automatically configures it. This mechanism does not
> support stacking and will just fail if you try it.

Does it mean I can use only one HAT with Raspberry Pi?

Comment: You've come to the right place, however, your question seems to lack any details. As such, the answer is yes, you could use these hats, and you can find a box to accommodate the lot by googling for the word "box" "case" or "enclosure" plus the dimensions you need. I bet your Czech is more fluent than mine, so you have a better shot of reading the specs of the hats to find out if they are compatible with each other.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev MonarcoHAT has on its web: Can I use multiple HATs with a single Raspberry Pi?
No, HATs are not stackable by definition. A HAT has to have an EEPROM onboard that automatically configures it. This mechanism does not support stacking and will just fail if you try it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure some extension boards are stackable, and not all have EEPROM. I'd ask the shop regarding two boards you want to use.